# Why isn't fbAsyncInit firing?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use the Facebook Javascript SDK in the following code, but the alert is never shown, no matter where in the fbAsyncInit I put it...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '205116556256919', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://lolkitten.org/', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
     alert('loading complete');
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<fb:like send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" />

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. (Btw, `channelUrl` should be URL of cross domain channel file which is HTML file containing JS-SDK and located at the same domain your application running on, it's unnecessary use full site homepage just for that purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running it from a local file on my computer. As a consequence, a link like (don't remember exactly) `//connect.facebook.com/all.js` was not resolved as desired and the expected JS not found.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution? did your channelUrl need to be something like 'http://lolkitten.org/channel.html', with that file containing <script src="//connect.facebook.com/all.js"></script> ? Did you run into problems working on a local host vs. a hosted website?

Having issues of my own with this channelUrl :/

Comment: It's some time ago now, but if I remember it right, it was working on the hosted website after uploading. I haven't checked that, but if you're experiencing the same issue, I guess it will be reported in the javascript console of your browser after loading.
In case you haven't used it yet: `F12` opens the inspector in any Browser, then (in Chrome) press `Esc` or (in Firefox) click on `Console`.

Comment: I realized that I was using Facebook Disconnect, a Chrome extension that was blocking that activity. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I had the Chrome Extension "Disconnect" running. Click the extension and click "Whitelist" site to fix the issue.